# How can I post data to an api using JavaScript and Json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I am trying to send some data (an object including name, email address, pdf file, etc) to an api using JavaScript (or jQuery) and Json, but I've never done it before and am not sure how to go about doing that.  This is what I've been messing around with so far just by piecing bits together, but I know it's not correct.  Thanks!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jencalloway/ZNXL8/)

```
var function sendData() {
    var anApi = //api url;
    var myData = {
        name: "John Smith",
        email: "johnsmith@email.com",
        pdfdoc: "pdfdoc"
    };

    console.log(sendData);

    $.post({
        type: "POST",
        url: anApi,
        data: myData,
        success: sucess,
        dataType: json
    });
}

sendData();
```

Comment: are `sucess` and `json` defined? is `anApi` pointing to a different origin? If yes, does that server support CORS? are you using a browser that supports CORS?

Comment: That is not how you use `$.post`.  That's the syntax for `$.ajax`.  The `$.post` syntax is `$.post(anApi, myData, success, 'json');`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure about the CORS support, I'm not really sure what that is.  success and json aren't defined, I'm guessing success should involve some sort of action, but does json have to be defined as something other than a datatype?

Comment: @JenCalloway: `json` is a variable, `'json'` is a string.

Comment: Do you mean to log `myData` or are you trying to log the function when it's called?

Comment: I'm trying to log myData, or just pass that data to the designated api.

Comment: @Jen, missed your reply. In that case you should be doing `console.log(myData);` rather than `console.log(sendData);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to stringify your data in-order to make the post request to the RESTAPI.

```
var r = $.ajax({
        url : someURL,
        type : 'POST',
        data : JSON.stringify( myData ),
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType : 'json',
        processData : false
    });

r.done( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    //your success handling code here
});

r.fail(function(  jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

check the jquery docs for more info regarding $.ajax() [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Why does he need to use `JSON.stringify`?  The API he is using might not want the data in that format.